# Is it possible to determine how the app was built?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ad-hoc-distribution

Is there any way to determine in code whether the app currently running is a developer, ad-hoc, or app store build?

Comment: Are you talking about identifying your own app or an arbitrary app you have on your device?

Comment: I'm building a static library that can be then put into any app. I want to put code into the library to determine what type of build is currently running.

Answer (score 1):

You could add C preprocessor definitions for each type to your build configuration, and use that definition to set a variable or flag in executable code.

Debug builds can be sometimes be detected by calling a benchmark loop whose run time varies significantly between -O0 and -Os optimization levels on a known device model.

Apple is reported to change an app's Info.plist in App store distributions, so you could count and checksum the plist items.

Comment: None of the above will work for a pre-compiled static lib without external input (or perhaps reading the Info.plist for additions/changes not officially documented by Apple).